# Trim or replace all commas and spaces from the String

Tags: java, android

Hi i am developing android application.Now i stuck in one problem. Let me give you a example to understand my problem.

**What I have is : kushal,mayurv,narendra,dhrumil,mark,  ,,,, ,**

**What i want is : kushal,mayurv,narendra,dhrumil,mark**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: both input and output string is same in your question then no need of any thing to do directly you can use the same string

Comment: @SunilKumar : the strings are not same i want to remove all the spaces and commas after "mark" word.

Comment: Why the mark word?  Do you need the first 5 words,

Comment: no the words are anyrhing and the size isn't fix of the words.

Comment: It's just hard to spot on first glance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the following code **to trim all unwanted comma and whitespaces**

```
String str = "kushal,mayurv,narendra,dhrumil,mark, ,,,, ";
        String splitted[] = str.split(",");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String retrieveData = "";
        for(int i =0; i<splitted.length; i++){
            retrieveData = splitted[i];
            if((retrieveData.trim()).length()>0){

                if(i!=0){
                    sb.append(",");
                }
                sb.append(retrieveData);

            }
        }

    str = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use regex to solve it. You want to remove all (,) that are followed by space or another (,). You also want to remove all (,) that isn't followed by a letter.

[Regex in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)

```
yourstring = yourstring.replaceAll("( ,)|(,,)", "");
```

Something like that, sorry that I can't help you more.

Comment: i don;t know the use of regex can u help me?

Comment: You have to create a pattern which is a regular expression to solve this. Please read about regular expressions , you will get an idea

Comment: In your pattern you should test for 3 cases: comma followed by whitespace, comma followed by another comma and comma followed by end of string. Replace all of them with the empty string should get the job done.

Comment: sure we want to remove all , not followed by a letter? e.g. "nickName,77FreeStyler1337" will cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

After trying to accomplish this myself, this seemed to work beautifully. Say you are attempting to do this for a string called myString:

```
    // replace all consecutive spaces and commas by a space and a comma respectively
    String sanitizedString = myString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll(",+", ",");

    // replace all resulting comma and space combinations
    sanitizedString = sanitizedString.replaceAll("( , )+|( ,)+|(, )+", ",").replaceAll(",+", ",");

    // remove leading and trailing commas (if any)
    sanitizedString = sanitizedString.replaceFirst("^,", "").replaceFirst(",$", "");

    // add a space between comma (merely for readability) **** optional ****
    sanitizedString = sanitizedString.replace(",", ", ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this its not a proper soution but will work in your case

```
String str = "kushal,mayurv,narendra,dhrumil,mark, ,,,, ,";

String new_str = str.replaceAll(","," "); //replace , with space

String temp = new_str.trim();             //remove trailing space

System.out.println(temp.replaceAll(" ",",")); // now replacing space with ,
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, a regex replaceAll() is the way to go.  However, in your case, do you eventually want an array of the individual Strings?  e.g. the equivalent of

```
new String[] { "kushal", "mayurv", "narendra", "dhrumil", "mark" }  ?
```

If so, you can do

```
String[] split = yourString.split(",");
```

but then go through split very carefully and look for empty Strings.

...

I see that Sunil beat me to it - check out that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems that you are trying to remove commas and spaces at the end of the string this might be what you are looking for, this pattern is usefull `[, ]+$`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[, ]+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("kushal,mayurv,narendra,dhrumil,mark, ,,,, ,");
String clean = m.replaceFirst("");
```

you can see this sample running [here](http://ideone.com/IGmLC)

**edit**
if you want an array with the individual entries `string.split` is the way to go (see [user949300 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8680316/86845))

Comment: This is a nice solution IF the problems occur only at the end of the String.  If you also want to remove empty stuff in the middle, e.g. blah,foo, ,,bar   then the regex gets more complicated.

Comment: agree... it's hard to generalize from a single example, I assumed that the issue would only be at the end of the string, Andreas Lindgren assumed that there would always be pairs of offending commas, etc..

Comment: yes the spaces and comma may be in the middle also. so that prob is solved by Sunil Kumar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
yourString=yourString.replaceAll("^\\W+|\\W+$","");
```